# Cannot implicitly convert 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int?>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'

Tags: linq

```
List<int> execFavoriteUsers = 
        (from exec in context.ExecutiveFavorites 
         where exec.ExecutiveUserID == model.UserID 
         select exec.ProfileUserID) 
        .ToList();
query = (from cast in query
        where execFavoriteUsers.Contains(cast.UserID) == false
        select cast);
```

But it works fine in Anoter system. How to fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried `List<int?> execFavoriteUsers = ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the type of ProfileUserID is an `int`?  Could it be a `Nullable<int>` or a `long` or a `uint`?

You could always just remove the explicit declaration and change it to `var` (in which case there can't be a conflict, because it infers the type implicitly).

Answer (score 0):

Try `List<int?>` instead of `List<int>`.

or if you need non-nullable ints:

```
List<int> execFavoriteUsers = 
        (from exec in context.ExecutiveFavorites 
         where exec.ExecutiveUserID == model.UserID 
         where exec.ProfileUserID.HasValue
         select exec.ProfileUserID.Value) 
        .ToList();
```